# Does not reconise variable

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to print an array. If I stop at `this.profile.classifications.classification` it works and returns `Math` when I add in `this.profile.classifications.classification.subclassification` it doesn't return anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Path: `mongoDB`

```
"classifications": {
      "classification": "Math",
      "subclassification": [
        "Class A",
        "Class B",
        "Class C"
      ]
    }
```

Path: `helper.js`

```
candidateSpecialisation: function () {
      var specialisations = (this.profile && this.profile.classifications && this.profile.classifications.classification && this.profile.classifications.classification.subclassification) ? this.profile.classifications.classification.subclassification.toString() : '';

      return specialisations.replace(/,/g, ", ");          
    },
```

Path: `template.html`

```
<p>{{candidateSpecialisation}}</p>
```

Comment: According to your example, `subclassification` is not a member of `classification`, it is a member of `classifications`.

Comment: Thanks. Such a noob mistake!